# Finding |a+b+c| using the dot product (vectors)

Tags: vectors

Getting a bit stuck with this question, can someone point me in the right direction.

Let $a, b, c$ be three unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that the angle between any two of them is $\pi/3$. Use the dot product to find $|a+b+c|$.

Answer (score 2):

For any vector $v$, $|v|^2=v\cdot v$. So here
$$|a+b+c|^2=(a+b+c)\cdot(a+b+c).$$
You have enough information to determine $a\cdot a$, $a\cdot b$ etc.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$|\vec a+\vec b+\vec c|^2=|\vec a|^2+|\vec b|^2+| c|^2+2\vec a.\vec b+2\vec b.\vec c+2\vec c. \vec a$$